# SQL issue Case give conversion error

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, the code worked fine. However as soon as I added the "Case" aspects, I get a **"Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Mail' to data type int.
"** error.

The value 'Mail' would be a value in the field: TABLEENTRIES.LONGDESCRIPTION, however the only field that is a INT type is re7.dbo.AttributeTypes.ATTRIBUTETYPESID

I have tried casting and converting all over the place, but I'm obviously doing something wrong or I wouldnt be here ;)

Any help would be muchly appreciated.

```
SELECT  RECORDS.CONSTITUENT_ID, 
        CONVERT(date, GIFT.DTE, 102) AS GiftDate,
        GIFT.Amount,
        APPEAL.APPEAL_ID AS Appeal,
        CAMPAIGN.CAMPAIGN_ID as Campaign,
        TABLEENTRIES.LONGDESCRIPTION as "Donation Channel",
        TABLEENTRIES.LONGDESCRIPTION as "Source Channel",
        gift.id as "Gift ID"

FROM
                  re7.dbo.CONSTIT_GIFTS INNER JOIN
                  re7.dbo.RECORDS ON re7.dbo.CONSTIT_GIFTS.CONSTIT_ID = re7.dbo.RECORDS.ID INNER JOIN
                  re7.dbo.GIFT INNER JOIN
                  re7.dbo.GiftSplit ON re7.dbo.GIFT.ID = re7.dbo.GiftSplit.GiftId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  re7.dbo.CAMPAIGN ON re7.dbo.GiftSplit.CampaignId = re7.dbo.CAMPAIGN.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  re7.dbo.APPEAL ON re7.dbo.GiftSplit.AppealId = re7.dbo.APPEAL.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  re7.dbo.FUND ON re7.dbo.GiftSplit.FundId = re7.dbo.FUND.ID ON re7.dbo.CONSTIT_GIFTS.GIFT_ID = re7.dbo.GIFT.ID INNER JOIN
                  re7.dbo.GiftAttributes ON re7.dbo.GIFT.ID = re7.dbo.GiftAttributes.PARENTID INNER JOIN
                  re7.dbo.AttributeTypes ON re7.dbo.GiftAttributes.ATTRIBUTETYPESID = re7.dbo.AttributeTypes.ATTRIBUTETYPESID inner JOIN
                  re7.dbo.TABLEENTRIES ON re7.dbo.AttributeTypes.CODETABLESID = case 
                    when re7.dbo.AttributeTypes.ATTRIBUTETYPESID = '242' then TABLEENTRIES.LONGDESCRIPTION
                    when re7.dbo.AttributeTypes.ATTRIBUTETYPESID = '637' then TABLEENTRIES.LONGDESCRIPTION
                    end
                  left JOIN
                  re7.dbo.GiftSoftCredit ON re7.dbo.GIFT.ID = re7.dbo.GiftSoftCredit.GiftId

WHERE 
(
   re7.dbo.GIFT.DTE >= '2016-04-29'
AND  re7.dbo.GIFT.TYPE = '1'
AND  re7.dbo.APPEAL.APPEAL_ID = 'TYE2016'
AND  re7.dbo.GiftAttributes.TABLEENTRIESID = re7.dbo.TABLEENTRIES.TABLEENTRIESID)
AND
NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM re7.dbo.GiftSoftCredit WHERE re7.dbo.records.ID = re7.dbo.GiftSoftCredit.ConstitId AND re7.dbo.gift.ID = re7.dbo.GiftSoftCredit.giftid
)
```

Comment: You do `CODETABLESID = TABLEENTRIES.LONGDESCRIPTION`. That seems to be a mixup

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `re7.dbo.AttributeTypes.CODETABLESID` is actually an integer column.  In that case, the value returned from your case statement, potentially `TABLEENTRIES.LONGDESCRIPTION` (I think 'Mail') is being converted to an integer also.

I'd need to understand better what your goal is in order to provide help fixing the SQL.

You may be better off trying to move that logic into the `where`.